# How could I send this information to another textarea on a different page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Just like how this javascript take the information and spits it into a textarea. I need to do that on a different webpage. I need to send the information to a webpage (Orderpage.html) with a simple textarea on it. This is what I have done so the information gets submitted to the textarea on the same page. I want it so when the user clicks on Complete order, they are taken to that webpage with the information.

```
function addShirt()
{ 
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += "You ordered " + document.getElementById("shirtQuantity").value;
    }

    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += " " + document.getElementById("shirtColor").value;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("smallSize").checked)
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += ", small shirt(s)";
    }

    if (document.getElementById("mediumSize").checked)
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += ", medium shirt(s)";
    }

    else if (document.getElementById("largeSize").checked)
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += ", large shirt(s)";
    }

    if (document.getElementById("giftWrap").checked)
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += " to be gift wrapped and delivered." + "\n";
    }

    else
    {
    document.getElementById("order").value += " to be delivered." + "\n";
    }
}
<html>
<head>
<title>Shirts</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="javascript.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="shirtInfo">
<select id="shirtColor">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="Grey">Grey</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="shirtQuantity" value=""><br />
<input type="radio" name="size" id="smallSize" value="small" checked="checked">Small<br />
<input type="radio" name="size" id="mediumSize" value="medium" checked="checked">Medium<br />
<input type="radio" name="size" id="largeSize" value="large" checked="checked">Large<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="giftWrap" value="">Giftwrap?<br />
<textarea id="order" rows="15" cols="50">
</textarea><br />
<input type="button" name="send" value="Add to Cart"    onClick="addShirt()"><br />
<input type="button" name="complete" value="Complete Order" onClick=""> <br>
<a href="pants.html">Pants</a><br />
<a href="hats.html">Hats</a><br />
<a href="orderpage.html">Order Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Remember_, HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Comment: Technically you could do this using a cookie or local storage, but it's probably not the best idea.

Comment: You can also send data via a query string , depends on the situation.

Comment: @Mave He definitely CAN. By using [Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: [I've answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30557164/1841194) 2 days ago. Have a look there.

Comment: @AliGajani But cookies make it stateful.

Comment: @abforce, they do but it won't be wrong to say _http still is stateless_

Answer (score 1):

In this case you're building a string in the `document.getElementById("order")` control, but since you're going to another page, that's not necessary. Just build it up in a variable. Let's call it "data".

```
var data;
data += "You ordered " + document.getElementById("shirtQuantity").value;
```

and so on. However, I would put the code that turns all these values into friendly text on the destination page instead. For now, we just need to store the data we want to send between pages:

```
var data;
data.quantity = document.getElementById("shirtQuantity").value;
```

and so on. Note that you don't have to define the properties ahead of time -- js will accept the dot notation and create new properties in the data object. You could also build up your data object as an array, if your information was more tabular in nature. It doesn't really matter for our purposes.

Once you have your data wrapped up in a nice, neat package, you'll need to stringify that object in order to pass it to the destination page. To do that, you run that data object through `JSON.stringify(data)`. On the destination page, you can decode it with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Now, you could just shove your stringified data in a querystring, but I'd suggest using session storage instead to transmit large-ish data between pages. This makes your URLs look neater and keeps the user from being able to edit the data in the querystring. On the "source" page you'll need something like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("shirtData", JSON.stringify(data));
```

This stores the "data" object, whatever it is, in session storage as a string under the name "shirtData". The "destination" page will need this code:

```
var shirt = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("shirtData"));
```

This retrieves the same string data, then converts it back into an object. I believe, given your example, these would go in your source page's submit event (or the `onclick` for whatever button the user uses to indicate they're done) and in the DOM Ready event on the destination, respectively.

Now, there's a detail to be careful of here. Since you've hard-coded the name of the item you're storing stuff in, a second run will overwrite the data you saved on the first run. I had exactly this problem when I built a report viewer -- the user could enter their report settings and open the report (call that Destination1), then change settings and open Destination2. If they then reloaded Destination1, it would use the last settings saved -- the ones that belonged to Destination2. You can overcome this by generating a random ID such as a GUID and appending it to the session storage name, then passing the ID in a querystring to the destination page.

Also be aware that session storage goes away whenever the browser closes. If you need to store something longer than that, you'll need to put it in a cookie. Also note that session storage is not secure and shouldn't be used to store anything sensitive.